# Using a variable as a column name used in HAVING SUM(@variable)

Tags: sql-server, sum

I want to SUM a column determined by the name of the column which will be passed in as a variable such as HAVING SUM(@variable)

For instance, I want to pass in the column HR and sum that, though I may want to sum by a different column

```
DECLARE @column varchar(20) = 'HR'

SELECT 
    Batting.playerID,
    SUM(G)      as G,
    SUM(AB)     as AB,
    SUM(R)      as R,
    SUM(H)      as H,
    SUM([2B])   as '2B',
    SUM([3B])   as '3B',
    SUM(HR)     as HR,
    SUM(RBI)    as RBI,
    SUM(SB)     as SB,
    SUM(BB)     as BB,
    SUM(HBP)    as HBP

FROM Batting 

GROUP BY playerID
HAVING SUM(@column) > 600
```

Comment: you can't do that. The only way is to use `Dynamic SQL`

Comment: You can do sort of what you want with a case statement `case when @column='HR' then HR ...etc...` but you cant change the name of the return column. Just call it Value or Result or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns the selected column as Val. Cant change the name of the column but can get the result:

```
DECLARE @column varchar(20) = 'HR'

select * from (
SELECT 
    Batting.playerID,
    sum(
        case 
            when @column='G' then G
            when @column='AB' then AB
            when @column='R' then R
            ... etc...
    end) as val
FROM Batting 
GROUP BY playerID
) q where val > 600
```